# How to import a sheet with images?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

```
Workbooks.Open fileName:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\Sea.xlsx"
Workbooks("Sea.xlsx").Sheets.Copy before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sky")
Workbooks("Sea.xlsx").Close False
```

This works but on Sea.xlsx there was a sheet with images.
Sheet is copied, but the images are not.
Instead, I have boxes with text:

```
This image cannot be currently displayed.
```

Comment: How were the images inserted?

Comment: Tim, I got the book with images via email. Have no info about the way they placed on sheet. Can I read this somewhere in Excel ?

Comment: Not exactly sure this is your problem, but try it:  Excel options >> Advanced >> make sure "cut, copy and sort inserted objects with their parent cells" is checked. Or add this code just before you copy the sheets: `Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True`

Comment: Also possible the original pictures were inserted as "links". You should be able to replace them with actual embedded pictures by copy/pastespecial to create a copy and then deleting the linked version.

Comment: Tim, the option you mentioned is checked by default, and not changed. I also tried `Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True` - the same result. Because I got the source file by mail, without any img folder for storing images, they are sure embeded, not linked. I tried about 10 times - only first time (after starting PC) - images were transfered - each other time - are not. I tried to restart PC again, restart Excel - no result. I googled and found some users with simmilar problem (excel 2010, not 2007). I'm starting to believe - it is a bag in xl2010.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem too and I think I've found a solution for it. For me the problem was that the sheet I wanted to copy was hidden. So I inserted row sheets(x).visible = true" to my code. The other I had to changed is that line "Application.Screenupdating = False" what I used previously have to be ignored.
After these change the picture was visible for me.
Hope this helps.